# If oscillatory motion is not simple (or chaotic), is it then by definition complex?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, definition, chaos-theory, complex-systems, integrable-systems

I'm trying to logically deduce or show that a specific type of motion is complex. It is two-dimensional oscillatory motion that can be expressed by coupled second order non-linear differential equations. Because it's non-linear it's clearly not expressing SHM, but does that mean that it *has* to be either complex or chaotic? Can I make that assumption, or is my reasoning flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by simple motion one is referring to SHM, the concept of *complexity* of the motion coincides with the integrability of the motion ( see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system) for a first idea about the concept ). Although integrability can become a subtle property, in particular if one starts to distinguish between *complete* or *partial* integrability, basically trajectories in the phase space of fully integrable hamiltonian systems are "simple" and reducible (via a non-linear transformation) to SHM.

In general, dynamical systems with more than one degree of freedom are non-integrable. However, this is a "probabilistic statement". Individual systems, even controlled by highly non-linear coupled equations of motion, may be integrable. For a partial list, see the section *List of some well-known classical integrable systems*  in the wikipedia page linked above.

Therefore, without a specific analysis of the particular dynamical system  you are interested, it is not possible to draw any conclusion on a general basis.